# How does compiler treat a const function?

Tags: c++, constants

I understand that a function is considered to be constant (bitwise constness) by compiler and if any statement brings modification in the state of object then compiler would throw an error as in Example 1.

**Example 1:**

```
class Test
{
public:
    int arr[5];
    void change(int j) const
    {
        arr[3]=j;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Test *ptr=new Test;
    ptr->change(3);
}
```

**Example2 :**
Now I have declared `arr` as <s>an array</s> a pointer, but the following seems to have been working on a few compilers — but on mine it doesn't. Does it mean it has UB? One of the legitimate explanations I came across mentions that we are not directly changing the object hence this is allowed. If so then why UB in my case? I'm using VS2008.

```
class Test
{
public:
    int *arr; //arr is an array
    int i;
    void change(int j) const
    {
        arr[3]=j;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Test *ptr=new Test;
    ptr->change(3);
}
```

Comment: int \*arr; // arr is ***NOT*** an array

Comment: And in the code given, it's not just not an array, it's not even a usable pointer; I believe it ends up being `nullptr` by default initialization (might even count as a POD type, with the memory going uninitialized?). So it's definitely broken.

Comment: @ShadowRanger it will be uninitialized.

Comment: @immibis: Yeah. So just truly terrible.

Comment: So if make this arr pointer to point to a member variable in the constructor, and then call this->change, then it should not be UB is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `int *ptr` does not declare `ptr` as an array. `ptr` is a ***pointer*** here.

Second, the reason your code exhibits undefined behaviour is that you're using an uninitialized pointer.

`ptr->change(3)` effectively does `ptr->arr[3] = 3;`. But you don't know what `ptr->arr` points to, so you don't know where you're writing the number 3 to. Maybe it'll point at some unused memory that's safe to overwrite, maybe it'll point to unallocated memory and crash your program as soon as you try to access it, or maybe it'll overwrite something important.

Separately: the reason it *compiles* is that while `arr` is part of the class `Test`, `*arr` isn't. From inside `change`, you can't alter `arr`, but you can alter `*arr`.

Comment: _ the reason it compiles is that while arr is part of the class Test, *arr isn't. From inside change, you can't alter arr, but you can alter *arr_ : you mean the address to which arr points to (incase int* arr) should remain the same , but the value can change? Because arr contains the address of some location which is considered to be a part of object while the memory location that is pointed at doesnt come in scope of object. Is that correct?